# Update CHMOD Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use this script **[Jeroen's Chmod Calculator](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/chmodcal3.shtml)** to calculate permissions and it works really well.

Currently it supports ticking the boxes and entering the numbers, but is there anyway it could be updated so as you enter the text equivalent of the permissions and the number and boxes update ?

Alternatively does anyone know of a script that already does this ?

I've not got a clue how to do this, so of there are any examples or something similar I@m happy to learn.

Thanks
**UPDATE**
this page support it.. 
http://liepins.de/projects/chmod/

But can I be done so the values convert as you type with out the need for a submit ?

Comment: do u use mac or pc? also found this: http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/

Comment: MAC, PC & Linux. Ideally I'd like this as a page I can put on my local web server.

Comment: mac has code which has brilliant permissions calculator.

Answer (score 0):

http://permissions-calculator.org/decode/

its called UNIX permissions.

just google it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't allow me to enter -rw-r--r-- and see it as 644, and then explain what 644 means.

My link to Jeroen's allows yo to enter 644, or select the permissions from the boxes, but not enter the text value and have it reverted back.

Comment: it does not seems like hard work though. 2 hours of JS coding tops. DIY! =)